# HDD S.M.A.R.T bad status error

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, hardware-failure

i have two SATA HDD on my computer,
one of them (not the one with OS) displays something like this at start up:

```
S.M.A.R.T Bad status backup and replace
```

and after that windows won't come up and F1 don't work even in safe mode mode.

i even tried on another computers too, but same thing happens.

i have some important data on it too, what can i do?

can i at least reach to my files anyway?

Comment: seriously? no one knows?

Comment: We have our life, our jobs, our tasks to do. We don't answer questions all day. You may have to wait longer than 24 minutes to get good answers.

Comment: The most likely case is that a critical system file or even the windows boot loader is on a corrupt sector. You can try a program like SpinRite to move the data to another sector but you still have the problem of your hdd failing.  Because this question has been asked before I am going to issue a downvote.

Answer (score 1):

If you are receiving this message, it is likely that the *only* thing you should do with the drive is attempt to recover data off it. Do Not attempt to boot an OS off this drive.

I say likely only because not all [smart stats](http://www.ariolic.com/activesmart/smart-attributes/reallocated-sectors-count.html) are created equal, and lesser stats like PoweredOnHoursCount are not necessarily indicative of a current imminent failure. you can boot from an ubuntu live CD and use their [Disk Utility](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gnome-disk-utility/) applet to determine exactly what stat is in a pre-fail or failed state.

If the failing metric is a critical one like ReallocatedSectorCount, (which is likely given the messages you are recieving), get a new drive, and either install an OS on it, or boot from a live CD. Attach the failing drive as a secondary disk, and attempt to back your files up to the new disk.

If you have sufficient disk space, I recommend you use [ddrescue](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html) to image the failing drive, so that if the drive does permanently fail you have copy of it to restore files from. Once you have an image, attempt to mount it and recover your data either using the booted file manager, or data recovery tools like [photorec](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html), [recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva), etc.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to test the drive with our SeaTools diagnostic utility:

http://www.seagate.com/support/downloads/seatools/

It is better to download the DOS version image. Burn it to a Disc. Boot from the disc. 
Seatools has two tests. Longtest and shorttest. Perform Shorttest first. If it fails, go for longtest. It will take some time. But it will fix the HDD Temporarily. If its fixed, Backup your data and give HDD to nearby service center.

You can stop this message after you change the smart setting in the bios. However, this practice is not the best.

You need to consider to replace the hard disk or at least backup the data on the disk regularly. re-install windows will affect the software, but not the hardware on it self

Answer (score -1):

You can try disabling SMART in BIOS for the particular hdd if its is enabled and hope your computer get pass the SMART error, load the OS and be able to back up your important files before disposing of the failing hdd.

Comment: Disabling SMART in BIOS would not allow the user to boot to Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound, why? I have always disabled SMART in BIOS on most of my build specially on new hdd's cause it eats up resources and yet I can boot to Windows.

Comment: @miggy, disabling smart is a very bad idea, and I have never seen a bit of evidence that SMART data collection causes any use of system resources whatsoever. SMART occurs exclusively on the hard disks integrated controller card, so it would not impact other adjacent components at all.

Comment: Disabling smart will not affect the windows booting. But its really a bad practice.

Comment: @miggy - My point is that. You can disable this feature but it won't solve the user's problem of not being able to boot Windows.  I am going to issue the downvote since this answer does not explain the reason, disabling S.M.A.R.T within BIOS would allow the user to boot into Windows.

Comment: The OP has 2 drives but said .. "one of them (not the one with OS) displays something like this at start up"..so I've assumed that the drive that has the OS is good. There are pc's (bios') that would stop at the SMART error and would not load the OS even if it is on a good drive just like the OP, so I recommended to the OP, on this particular situation, to try to disable SMART in BIOS for that "particular" drive in hope that he could get pass the error and be able to load the OS which the OP said on the good drive and recover important files on the failing drive.